# Software center disappeared [19.10]

Tags: software-installation, software-center, software-sources

I have had trouble with sound (now fixed) since upgrading to 19.10, and in the middle of trying the common solutions, the Software Center "disappeared".
I got aware of quite late, so I don't know what caused it.

Anyway, would you know how to reinstall it ?
Trying `sudo apt-get install software-center` doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! “Doesn’t work” is an insufficient description. Please [edit] your post to add the output of the command. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text.

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu Software Center was discontinued after 16.04. The default software application is now Gnome Software.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Answer (score 1):

(Updated)
Did you try updating it ?

Just try :

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then :

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-center
```

Then it will be installed. 
You could also use Synaptic package manager.

Comment: The old software center is discontinued and we use `gnome-software` now.

Comment: Thanks @mchid. It helped.